# SQL Server 2008 Query: Multiple column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I need to select all values where `project_status_id = 2` OR `project_ship_date` has a date in the past year. Not really sure how this is accomplished.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.id, p.name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), s.ship_date, 109) AS ship_date, 
    sp.name as species, p.quoted_sf
FROM 
    ProjectTracking.dbo.projects AS p
LEFT JOIN 
    ProjectTracking.dbo.shipments AS s ON p.id = s.project_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ProjectTracking.dbo.segments AS seg ON p.id = seg.project_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ProjectTracking.dbo.species AS sp ON seg.specie_id = sp.id
WHERE 
    sp.name LIKE '%maple%' 
    AND (p.project_status_id = 2 OR s.ship_date > "last year?")
```

**Note**: `p.project_status_id` has possible values of `1,2,10,11`

**Note #2**: If `p.project_status_id != 2` then `s.ship_date` must be specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),s.ship_date,109) AS ship_date, sp.name as species, p.quoted_sf
FROM ProjectTracking.dbo.projects AS p
LEFT JOIN ProjectTracking.dbo.shipments AS s ON p.id = s.project_id
LEFT JOIN ProjectTracking.dbo.segments AS seg ON p.id = seg.project_id
LEFT JOIN ProjectTracking.dbo.species AS sp ON seg.specie_id = sp.id
WHERE sp.name LIKE '%maple%' AND
(p.project_status_id IN (1,2,10,11) OR s.ship_date > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) )
```

Comment: I'll try that again - last time I tried it the server locked up. Maybe too much data?

Comment: it's a simple query but may be the table structure and data we don't assume.more over you have using left join and Like so it will definitely consume lot of time @visevo

Comment: gotcha. is there a more efficient way to run this query? @mohan111